# JBossWS change wsdl url

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jbossws

I have a web application deployed on JBoss 5.1.0 with a couple of webservices.

When i use the JBossWS console to see the registered service endpoints, all my webservices follow the same URL pattern:

http://my_machine:8080/some_default_name/webservice_name?wsdl

The problem is that i need to change the some_default_name part of the URL.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you call `some_default_name` is the of your web-app context. The simple way to change it is to rename your war (should be /server//deploy/some_default_name.war).

Jboss uses Tomcat as web container. You can configure `path` on [Context element](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) to change your context name as well.